# Installing D8 using composer, with LAMPP destination is unclear

Tags: installation, composer

Documentation is unclear about the final destination of site.
XAMPP looks for site in opt/lampp/htdocs, do I run composer from here?  If so will it then create a dir called web with drupal inside that dir?
-OR-
Do I simply run composer and use the created web dir to hold the files and then manually copy the data to htdocs dir? (this seems wrong)
-OR-
Do I tweak xampp to look elsewhere for the drupal dir

Previously I unzipped, copied drupal folder to htdocs dir.

Answer (score 1):

Run your composer install command from opt/lampp/htdocs and put a . at the end to tell it to install in the current directory and that should do the trick e.g.

```
composer install drupal/drupal .
```